# Jquery image fade - losing mouse over effects

Tags: javascript, events, jquery-plugins

I try to do this image effects: http://coverdesign.ro/teste/lore/ but sometimes when the mouse move from one object to another it lose the hover state;
I use this js script:

```
 $(function () {

  $('div.fade').hover(function() {
        fade = $('> div', this);
        nume = $(this).attr('id');
        $("."+nume).addClass("mselect");
        if (fade.is(':animated')) {
            fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
        } else {
            fade.fadeIn(1000);
        }
    }, function () {
       /* var fade = $('> div', this);
        var nume = $(this).attr('id');*/
        $("."+nume).removeClass("mselect");
        if (fade.is(':animated')) {
            fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
        } else {
            fade.fadeOut(500);
        }
    });


        $('#menu a').hover(function() { 
        var nume = $(this).attr('class'); 
        var fade = $('#'+nume+' > div');
        //$("."+nume).addClass("mselect");
        if (fade.is(':animated')) {
            fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
        } else {
            fade.fadeIn(2000);
        }
    }, function () {
        var nume = $(this).attr('class'); 
        var fade = $('#'+nume+' > div');
        if (fade.is(':animated')) {
            fade.stop().fadeTo(2000, 0);
        } else {
            fade.fadeOut(2000);
        }
    });
});
```

What actually happens is, sometimes when the mouse is moved from the cat to the phone, the hover does not get activated. If you play around with the page you will realise that the color change of the cat and the phone, sometimes does not happen due to hover state being lost.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You want the object to keep the hover state even when the object is not being hovered over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this line of code

```
$('div.fade').hover(function() {
```

is causing a problem in identifying the proper div. You could try uniquely identifying each menu item/image and handle it accordingly.

Comment: is there any other way to make that ? will be a little ugly if I call the effects for each object :-s
Anyway ..thanks for your time

Comment: Yes I agree. What you could probably try is adding an id 1, 2, 3, 4 and try to get the value of the hovered item and generate the id which it has and assign the effect for it.